# Http.get to restfull api returns half the data.Angular 4 drupal 8

Tags: angular, drupal-8

hey guys i am running on a strange scenario since i am new to angular.My issue is i am receiving less data than the server gives me.i actually receive 31 of 42 items in total. i have a RESTexport from drupal which on browser gives me this :

```
    42items:[{"uid":[{"value":1}],"uuid":[{"value":xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}],"langcode":[{"value":"en"}],"preferred_langcode":[{"value":"en"}],"preferred_admin_langcode":[],"name":[{"value":"waw"}],"mail":[{"value":"some@gmail.com"}],"timezone":[{"value":"Asia\/Dubai"}],"status":[{"value":true}],"created":[{"value":xxxxxx}],"changed":[{"value":xxxxxxx}],"access":[{"value":xxxxxxxx}],"login":[{"value":xxxxxxxxxx}],"init":[{"value":"some@gmail.com"}],"roles":[{"target_id":"administrator","target_type":"user_role","target_uuid":xxxxxxxx"}],"default_langcode":[{"value":true}],"field_address":[],"field_bio":[],"field_dob":[],"field_facebook":[],"field_fax":[],"field_first_name":[],"field_gender":[],"field_instagram":[],"field_interested_sports":[],"field_lang_prefered":[],"field_lang_spoken":[],"field_last_name":[],"field_mobile":[],"field_nationality":[],"field_newsletters":[],"field_phone":[],"field_skype":[],"field_snapchat":[],"field_sports":[],"field_spots":[],"field_twitter":[],"field_website":[],"field_youtube":[],"user_picture":[{"target_id":3,"alt":"","title":"","width":85,"height":48,"target_type":"file",xxxxxxxxxxxx"}]}]
```

on the angular side now i do http.get to receive the data

```
    getdata(){ this._userdataservice.getUser()
.subscribe(user => {
 this.user=user
console.log(this.user,"user")})}
```

and what i receive is this:31 out of42

```
    changed:Array(1)
    created:Array(1)
    default_langcode:Array(1)
    field_address:Array(0)
    field_bio:Array(0)
    field_dob:Array(0)
    field_facebook:Array(0)
    field_fax:Array(0)
    field_first_name:Array(0)
 field_gender:Array(0) field_instagram:Array(0) field_interested_sports:Array(0) field_lang_prefered:Array(0)
field_lang_spoken:Array(0) field_last_name:Array(0)
field_mobile:Array(0) field_nationality:Array(0)
field_newsletters:Array(0) field_phone:Array(0) field_skype:Array(0)
field_snapchat:Array(0) field_sports:Array(0) field_spots:Array(0)
field_twitter:Array(0) field_website:Array(0)
field_youtube:Array(0)langcode:Array(1) name:Array(1) uid:Array(1)
user_picture:Array(1) uuid:Array(1)
```

Comment: 31 what out of 42 what? The JSON you posted isn't valid JSON, BTW.

Comment: when i go on the browser on the api link i get 42 objects there (the json export is from d8 so it has to be valid ) my JSON representation  here is the copy of console.log that gets 31 only . in angular i can use all those 31 objects but i need the remaining ones !

Comment: It's definitely not valid. Just paste it in any online JSON validator. It's also unclear why you would name user an array of 42 objects (if that's what you mean, because since the JSON is invalid, it's hard to know what you get, and what you expect to get).

Comment: Valid JSON just tried. Dont get confused with the json in the script here cause the XXXXXX is data i deleted. but the original export is valid

Comment: my impression so far is that it might have to do with my authentication on drupal

Comment: If you post invalid stuff, and don't explain clearly what you expect to get and what you get instead, we can't help.